# # and $ not working in JSP Page in IE

Tags: javascript, jsp, internet-explorer

I have the following function in my `JavaScript` to make sure that the `dropdown` on my page works `onHover`.
**JavaScript :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(200);
        }, function() {
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(200);
    });
});
```

I also have another piece of code in the same that that makes the elements in the dropdown clickable. The code for this is :

```
<ul  class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#" onclick="dispUsers()"> View All </a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="#"> Edit </a></li>
    <li><a href="#" nclick="clearfield();displayDeleteForm();">Delete</a></li>
</ul>
```

When I run the `page`, I get the following **error :**
`$ is undefined` in the `onHover` funcitonality. 
Say for the time being, I comment out this piece of code and try to run the `page` hoping to click on the dropdown and see all the options. I get the following **error** when I do this : 
`# is an Invalid character` in all the references that are made in the inside the dropdown. Note that I am using `Internet Explorer` and have recently upgraded to `IE 11`. The same does not happen to work on `Chrome` either. 
Help much appreciated!

Note that I have included the following abut it is still not working: 
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: You haven't included jQuery on the page

Comment: check my edit. I have included it already. Just forgot to post the same. It is still not working but.

Comment: The invalid character error is coming from: onclick="#". There is no need for this right? The other error maybe due to where you are putting each script on your page.  If you look at this simplified fiddle you can see that if you click on the links, it calls correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/staceyburnsy/tbxpfqng/1/